# Scrape Understat Data into R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am currently trying to scrape [the first team table](https://understat.com/league/EPL/2020) into `R`. However, I'm having a lot of trouble getting the current table. My code is currently

```
xg_page <- "https://understat.com/league/EPL/2020"
xg_scraped_page <- read_html(xg_page)
xg_df <- xg_scraped_page %>%
  html_nodes("script")
xg_df <- stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(str_subset(xg_df, "teamsData"))
xg_df <- sub(".*?\\'(.*)\\'.*", "\\1", xg_df)
xg_df <- fromJSON(xg_df, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE, flatten = TRUE)
 # get teams data
xg_df <- lapply(
  xg_df, function(x) {
    df <- x$history
    df$team_id <- x$id
    df$team_name <- x$title
    df
  }
)
teams_df <- do.call("rbind", xg_df)
teams_xg_xga <- data.frame(teams = teams_df$team_name,
                           xG = teams_df$xG,
                           xGA = teams_df$xGA)
```

which appears to scrape in 600 rows of data rather than just 20, one for each team. I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I've had trouble grabbing `"league chemp"` from the table id as well. I'm probably missing something simple, but can't figure out what it is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions.

### Using json data from the page

I don't know this data enough, but here you have row details, you can summarise it. Script in the page probably do that?

Following your code, an example:

```r
teams_summary <- teams_df %>% 
  # filter(between(lubridate::as_date(date), as.Date('2021-04-01'), as.Date('2021-04-09'))) %>% # test on some filtered green dates like on webpage
  group_by(team_name) %>% 
  summarise(M = n(),
            W = sum(wins),
            D = sum(draws),
            L = sum(loses),
            G = sum(scored),
            GA = sum(missed), 
            PTS = sum(pts),
            xG  = sum(xG),
            xGA  = sum(xGA),
            xPTS = sum(xpts),
            evol_xG = xG - G,
            evol_xGA = xGA - GA,
            evol_xPTS = xPTS - PTS) %>% 
  arrange(desc(PTS)) %>% 
  mutate(`N°` = row_number()) %>% 
  select(`N°`, everything())

teams_summary
```

```
# A tibble: 20 x 15
    `N°` team_name                   M     W     D     L     G    GA   PTS    xG   xGA  xPTS evol_xG evol_xGA evol_xPTS
   <int> <chr>                   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1 Manchester City            31    23     5     3    66    21    74  64.9  24.2  69.2  -1.10     3.17     -4.77 
 2     2 Manchester United          30    17     9     4    58    33    60  50.3  33.8  51.1  -7.70     0.751    -8.91 
 3     3 Leicester                  30    17     5     8    53    34    56  45.2  36.3  46.6  -7.76     2.29     -9.44 
 4     4 West Ham                   30    15     7     8    48    37    52  46.0  37.1  47.1  -2.02     0.111    -4.86 
 5     5 Chelsea                    30    14     9     7    46    30    51  51.1  25.0  59.4   5.15    -5.01      8.42 
 6     6 Liverpool                  30    14     7     9    51    36    49  53.4  37.4  51.8   2.40     1.39      2.80 
 7     7 Tottenham                  30    14     7     9    51    32    49  43.8  39.6  43.4  -7.19     7.56     -5.57 
 8     8 Everton                    29    14     5    10    41    38    47  39.4  39.0  39.4  -1.61     0.998    -7.63
```

close from this today:
[image: website screenshot]

### Using Selenium (here RSelenium)

In browser, this JS code from understat.com does statistics online on JSON data:

```
function viewChemp(_data) {
    var tableChempData  = [];
    $.each(_data, function(i, team){
        var data = {
            number          : null,
            team            : team.title,
            matches         : 0,
            wins            : 0,
            draws           : 0,
            loses           : 0,
            goals           : 0,
            ga              : 0,
            points          : 0,
            xG              : 0,
            NPxG            : 0,
            xGA             : 0,
            NPxGA           : 0,
            NPxGD           : 0,
            ppda            : 0,
            ppda_allowed    : 0,
            deep            : 0,
            deep_allowed    : 0,
            xPTS            : 0,
            id              : team.id
        },
        ppda_temp = {att: 0, def: 0},
        ppda_allowed_temp = {att: 0, def: 0};
        $.each(team.history, function(j, match){
            data.matches += 1;
            switch(match.result) {
                case 'w':
                    ++ data.wins;
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    ++ data.draws;
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    ++ data.loses;
                    break;
            }
            data.goals += match.scored;
            data.ga += match.missed;
            data.points += match.pts;
            data.xG += match.xG;
            data.NPxG += match.npxG;
            data.xGA += match.xGA;
            data.NPxGA += match.npxGA;
            data.deep += match.deep;
            data.deep_allowed += match.deep_allowed;
            data.xPTS += match.xpts;
            
...
...
...
```

To get the table as printed in browser another option using Selenium and rvest:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr)

# java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar 

remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4444L, # change port according to terminal 
  browserName = "firefox"
)

remDr$open()
# remDr$getStatus()
remDr$navigate("https://understat.com/league/Ligue_1/")

elem_chemp <- remDr$findElement(using="xpath", value="//*[@id='league-chemp']")
results_champ <- read_html(elem_chemp$getElementAttribute('innerHTML')[[1]]) %>% 
  html_table()
```

To scrape the second table with players stats, you can loop over table pagination by clicking with Selenium, we need max page number and to move at this element in browser:

```
# max page number of table
elem_player <- remDr$findElement(using="xpath", value="//*[@id='league-players']")
elem_player_page_number <- remDr$findElement(using="id", value = "league-players")
player_page_number <- read_html(elem_player_page_number$getElementAttribute('innerHTML')[[1]]) %>% 
  html_nodes('li.page') %>% 
  html_attr('data-page') %>% 
  as.integer() %>% 
  max()


# move to this table via script
remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",args = list(elem_player))

# or scroll at the bottom of page
# body_b <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
# body_b$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
# then you can go to top
# body_b$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "home"))


i <- 1
one_table_at_a_time <- function(i){
  # move on the right page
  # elem_click <- remDr$findElement('xpath', glue::glue('//*[contains(@data-page,"{i}")]'))
  elem_click <- remDr$findElement('xpath', 
                                  glue::glue('//*[@id="league-players"]//*[normalize-space(@data-page) = "{i}"]'))
  remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = elem_click)
  elem_click$click()
  
  # get the table for 10 players
  elem_player <- remDr$findElement(using="xpath", value="//*[@id='league-players']")
  results_player <- read_html(elem_player$getElementAttribute('innerHTML')[[1]]) %>% 
    html_table()
  
  results_player %>% 
    .[[1]] %>% 
    filter(!is.na(Apps)) %>% 
    return()
  
}

# one_table_at_a_time(3) %>% View
# loop over pages
resu <- 1:player_page_number %>% purrr::map_df(one_table_at_a_time)
```

I find it funny so I have made a video on this selenium usage.

[video link](https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/udJAi5dx2UQ?cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=en) (subtitles are available)

Comment: Thanks, however, I am more concerned with the process of scraping the table from the webpage.

Comment: Ok, I know. But I'm not sure the table is scrapable, I think the table is calculated on demand (test, you can change dates, and the stats are refreshed depending on dates : there are probably not as many tables as date choices).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the {understatr} package: https://github.com/ewenme/understatr

If you can't find exactly what you need, you can check the source code of the package to see how it's scraping things from the website, I've been able to create some stuff of my own based on it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `understat` and was mostly able to scrape data. I think @Guilluame is right, the table isn't easily scrapable since its constantly updated. I was able to go to Fbref and get the same data and pulled it into `R` that way.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the {understatr} package. I discover. Also see this post from @hrbrmstr following mine on the subject: https://rud.is/b/2021/04/12/check-developer-tools-first-to-avoid-heavy-ish-dependencies/